# Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]' cannot be serialized

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

As per the following article, I have defined my service contract as

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> HelloAsync(string name);
}
```

However, when I try to generate a proxy, I get the message Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]' cannot be serialized.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you using the async CTP? That syntax is not yet part of C#

Comment: @JohnSaunders

yes, I am using ctp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support for Task-based asynchronous operations is only available in the version 4.5 of the .NET Framework Unless you're using the developer preview which was made available in mid-September, this won't work.

Comment: Doesn't this work with Async CTP? I am using Async For with VS 2010 SP1

Comment: No, it is not available in that CTP. It's only available in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good answer: http://mylifeandcode.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-cause-and-solution-for.html

Seems need to re-generate proxy classes - instead of "Generate task-based operations" need to choose "Generate asynchronous operations".